# Filesystem check on mp3-player?

Tags: linux, windows, mp3, chkdsk

Sometimes depending on how the files were copied to the device, it stops to play, randomly on a part of the memory.

On linux/debian I tried to use carefully:

> "lsblk" or "sudo fdisk -l"
>
> sudo fsck /dev/sdb (or with switch -a)

which seemed to work.

How it could be done for example with a chkdsk thru commandline or gui on windows, if the device is not recognized as a drive ?

Comment: So the device initially is set to have a drive letter by Windows, then while using it it "disappears"? Sounds like communication errors, maybe the USB cable / port / device is going bad...

Comment: No, it shows the mp3-player as well, but not as drive, I also tried "Diskpart list disk/partition". Thanks